# Jasmine test fails but 'expected' and 'toBe' strings seem equal?

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, pipe, separator

I am working on an angular(2.4.0)/typescript application that uses a custom currency pipe which internally uses angular's built-in CurrencyPipe for formatting inputted currency strings for both '*en-CA*' and '*fr-CA*' Canadian locales. While writing unit tests for the french case, for the happy-path case of expecting formatted output for a given valid input string,

```
describe('for French locale', () => {
 // get the mock custom currency pipe instance for 'fr-CA' locale as 'currencyPipeForFR'
 it('should be formatted for fr-CA locale', () => {
  expect(currencyPipeForFR.transform('7500')).toBe('7 500 $');
 });
});
```

I am getting this error,

```
Expected '7 500 $' to be '7 500 $'.
```

I did check the *instance of* of the transformed result and it is a `String`. What am I missing? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the culprit was the *grouping/thousand separator* used by the angular's built-in *CurrencyPipe* for '*fr-CA*' locale. While checking for the UTF-16 code unit value for each character in the string, I was able to see the *grouping/thousand separator* character (\u00A0) at index *1* (between *7* and *5* of the pipe's output value '*7 500 $*') was different from the normal space bar character (\u0020). The space just before the '*$*' sign in the expected value '*7 500 $*' was equivalent to \u0020 (normal space bar character) as it was manually appended to the built-in pipe’s formatted result within the custom pipe’s logic.

Hence, as a generic solution to such instances (not really required for my use case) of using locale-dependent pipes (CurrrencyPipe, DecimalPipe), I was able to get the unit test to correctly check for the expected value by making use of the `toLocaleString()` method of `Number.prototype` property like this,

```
describe('for French locale', () => {
 // get the custom currency pipe instance for 'fr-CA' locale as 'currencyPipeForFR'
 const thousandSeparator = () => {
  return (1000).toLocaleString('fr-CA').substring(1, 2);
 }
 it('should be formatted for fr-CA locale', () => {
  expect(currencyPipeForFR.transform('7500')).toBe('7' + thousandSeparator() + '500 $');
 });
});
```

Comment: That's quite exhaustive answer. I would say that hardcoding the value in tests is always more preferable, `7 + String.fromCharCode(parseInt('a0', 16)) ...`

Comment: @estus - good point. For the particular test spec, that would suffice. But, as pointed out in my answer, the idea was to show an easy way to fetch the locale specific separator used in pipes just by knowing the locale itself and not actually having to dig up the char or its corresponding unicode. Thanks.

Comment: just some background: utf16 'a0' is "no break space" (html encoded `&nbsp;`), so `7 500` will not break at the end of line to `7(newline)500`. Same for `100,00  €` (so `100,00(newline)€` would not happen, that would look silly...). Btw, `&nbsp;` is not used when you format Date() (so you CAN have day on one line and month on another)